# How can i retrieve all child nodes of unique key in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, geofire

I am creating an application which uses Firebase and Geofire. I am able to store values in FireBase.

In Geoquery I am getting the keys which are in that particular area.
 I want to retrieve all the child nodes of that particular key only. how do I do that?

[i want to retrieve the child values of the key -KpzaWx6FfdT27FlEoaZ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KafO.png)

how do I do that?

please give the full code for getting all the values of **-KpzaWx6FfdT27FlEoaZ** <---- this key only I should get

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `user_Location` is the direct child of your Firebase root, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userLocationRef = rootRef.child("user_Location").child("-KpzaWx6FfdT27FlEoaZ").child("l");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Double lat = ds.child("0").getValue(Double.class);
        Double long = ds.child("0").getValue(Double.class);
        Log.d("TAG", lat + " / " + long);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userLocationRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AlexMamo

Comment: You're welcome Harish. So, if you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!